# Python Kivy DLL load failed on using ArcGIS ArcPy

Tags: python, kivy, arcpy

I am running Kivy and Python properly when it is only Kivy as

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') 

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
```

but when I add ArcGIS Python library called ArcPy like below

```
import arcpy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') 

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
```

I am getting following error:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    

Traceback               
    <module>    <module3>   5       
    <module>    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py    327     
    <module>    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py 219     
    <module>    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py  89      
    init kivy.graphics.instructions (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:14640)    kivy\graphics\vbo.pxd   7       
    init kivy.graphics.vbo (kivy\graphics\vbo.c:5482)   kivy\graphics\compiler.pxd  1       
    init kivy.graphics.compiler (kivy\graphics\compiler.c:2983) kivy\graphics\shader.pxd    5       
    init kivy.graphics.shader (kivy\graphics\shader.c:11990)    kivy\graphics\texture.pxd   3       
    init kivy.graphics.texture (kivy\graphics\texture.c:31800)  kivy\graphics\fbo.pxd   5       
    init kivy.graphics.fbo (kivy\graphics\fbo.c:7683)   kivy\graphics\fbo.pyx   84       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?